# Reliable way to tell when access to the camera has been granted in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript, camera

In my little Flash app, I need to know when the user has granted access to the camera. The documented way to tell whether this has happened is to listen for the camera's "unmuted" event, like so:

```
private function handleCameraStatus(event:StatusEvent):void {
    try {
        _logger.log("Camera status event {code:" + event.code + ", type:" + event.type + "}");
        switch (event.code) {
            case "Camera.Muted": 
                _eventHandler.raiseError("Camera became unavailable");
                break;
            case "Camera.Unmuted": 
                _eventHandler.raiseEvent("onUserMediaRetrieved", _mic, _cam);
        }
    } catch (e:Error) {
        _eventHandler.raiseError("Error handling connection status", e);
    }
}
```

This is the method that is recommended in several places on Adobe's site, for instance, [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html) and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSfffb011ac560372f3fa68e8912e3ab6b8cb-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d37).

The problem with this approach is that if the user has added the site to his or her list of trusted sites (so that access automatically gets granted, without having to click "Allow" in the Adobe Flash Player Settings dialog box), the `Camera.Unmuted` event never gets fired. (At least, this is what my testing on several different sites indicates.) This makes listening to `Camera.Unmuted` more-or-less useless as a way to determine whether you've actually got access to the camera.

Any other suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if the camera is muted after you retrieve a reference to it. This allows you to skip the entire status check if access is already granted, as in the case of the user marking the site as "trusted."

I also recommend manually raising the security panel in the muted case, as this will bring up the "remember me" dialog, allowing your users to save their preference and removing the nag next time.

Here is some pseudo-ish code:

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();

if (camera.muted) {
    Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);

    // add status listener and all that
}
else 
{
    // start the camera/etc
}
```

This Adobe example is more fleshed out:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera()